# WP Woocommerce array to show products based on title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use the following array to show the products in category based on page title. If the title is `CUHA`, I want it to show product category `CUHA-подови`. However, I can't seem to make it work.

This is the code that I am using. It works okay, but when I try to use `get_the_title()` in the array it crashes. I know that the problem is in my array skills.

```
<?php  
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'product_cat' => 'get_the_title() . - . подови' );

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
  global $product; 
  echo '<br /><a href="'.get_permalink().'">' . woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</a>';
  endwhile; 
  wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

Comment: `'product_cat' => get_the_title() . ' -  подови'` ?

Comment: So simple yet it works :) i feel ashamed of myself :P . But can you tell me if i want to get CUHA-подови why ' - подови' with spaces work ? does the string not recognise the spaces ? and please feel free to make your comment in an answer so that i can vote it as a solution